# Laravel View::make render и HTML сущности

Tags: php, html, laravel, view, entity

Задача: нужно из контроллера вставить один шаблон **view1** в другой **view2**. При этом оба шаблона - blade (view1.blade.php и view2.blade.php).

Метод контроллера возвращает view2: `return view('view2', $extras);` 
Во view2 есть следующий блок:

```
@if(!empty($extras))
 @section('extras')
  {{ $extras}}
 @stop
@endif
```

**view1** формируется таким образом:

```
$view1 = View::make('view1', array('id' => $id));
$extras = $view1 ->render();
```

Во **view1** не просто HTML, там так же ожидаются переменные.

**Проблема:** на выходе у **view1** вместо обычного HTML - сущности:

```
&lt;div class=&quot;layer&quot;&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;div class=&quot;row custom&quot;&gt;
&lt;div class=&quot;col-xs-12&quot;&gt;
```

Пробовал:

```
htmlspecialchars_decode($extras);
e($extras)
{!! $extras !!}
{!! html_entity_decode($extras) !!}
```

Ничего не помогает, кроме нативной **php** функции `html_entity_decode($extras);`

Почему встроенные в Laravel функции в данном случае не решают проблему? Всё-таки они не спроста реализованы и мне кажется я что-то не так делаю.

P.S. Ну и вопрос на засыпку: насколько корректно вообще вставлять один шаблон в другой таким образом? Да, я в курсе что это можно делать из самого blade шаблона, но всё же - вопрос актуальный.

Comment: $extras = View::make('extras', array('id' => $id));
$data = $extras->render(); это для чего вам?

Comment: @PaulWall Мне нужно один blade шаблон вставить в другой из контроллера.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Прошерстил ресурсы западных коллег и пришёл к выводу, что, всё же, `View::make()->render()` это нормальная практика: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29253979/laravel-5-display-html-with-blade (обсуждение по ссылке будет в том числе полезно тем, кто не совсем понимает отличия `{{ $var }}` и `{!! $var !!}`)

Не зря же разработчики Лары реализовали этот метод.

Моя задача решилась таким образом:

Создаём массив с элементом html который будет содержать в себе рендер blade мини-шаблона, который нужно вставить по тем или иным причинам в главный шаблон:

```
$layer = array('html' => View::make('layer.detail', array('data' => $data))->render());
```

И передаём его в возвращаемый контроллером blade шаблон:

```
return view('page.detail', array('layer' => $layer));
```

В шаблоне `page.detail` в месте, где нужно вставить полученный html, пишем:

```
{!! html_entity_decode($layer['html']) !!}
```

Я новичок в Laravel, но для меня решение работает.

Answer (score 1):

Короче я не въеду что Вы там делаете и почему, но вот такой вариант предлагаю, учитывая, что в $data находится:

```
<div class="layer"></div>
<div class="row custom"></div>
<div class="col-xs-12"></div>
```

То в контроллере:

```
return view('extras', compact('data'));
```

И во вьюшке тупо:

```
{!! $data !!}
```

Зачем у вас там render я ума не приложу вообще

Comment: Согласен, объяснение в вопросе кривое - переформулировал. Вкратце: нужно один blade шаблон вставить в другой из контроллера. При этом вставляемая вьюха это не просто html из 3 строк, там ожидаются свои переменные, для этого и рендер - View::make('view1', array('id' => $id)) - на выходе дает просто объект (разве нет?), render делает из него html который и нужно вставить. Про то что можно вкладывать одну вьюху в другую непосредственно из blade я в курсе, в данном случае нужно именно так - из контроллера.

Comment: давайте проще, что по факту у Вас за задача стоит, потому что передать html код и переменные можно в сто раз проще

Comment: Задача такая: есть 3 вьюхи: 1. общий шаблон страниц всего сайта от <html><body> до </body></html>, в нем есть секция 'content', в эту секцию вставляется - 2. шаблон текущей страницы (@extends и @section), возвращаемый контроллером return view(), и есть еще 3. шаблон - так называемый леер, который должен перекрывать весь сайт затемнением (типа попап окно). Третий шаблон должен обязательно принимать объект и вставляться сразу за <body> в первом шаблоне. Объект формируется тем же контроллером, что и возвращает второй шаблон. Третий шаблон контентно зависит от второго.

Comment: А второй шаблон вставляется в первый далеко не сразу за <body>, поэтому вставлять просто третий во второй - не тот вариант.

Comment: Поэтому я сделал так: в первом шаблоне прописал еще одну секцию - layer (сразу за <body>), во втором шаблоне сделал @section('layer') и в это место пихаю срендеренную третью вьюху, как и видно из вопроса. По логике, html третьей вьюхи идёт в 1 шаблон сразу за <body> где и был прописан @yield('layer'), это и происходит, но насколько я правильно это реализовал?

Comment: вот по поводу леера подробнее, ничего не понял зачем он и что делает

Comment: леер это 1) div который затемняет весь экран и 2) окно поверх затемнения из пункта 1, в котором что-то есть (какой-то контент). Чтобы оно отображалось как надо нужно положить его в максимально верхний узел в иерархии DOM документа - в <body>. В css у леера position: fixed (или relative), z-index и прочее.

Comment: воу воу не надо делать это через контроллер)))) это порно какое-то)) что вызывает у вас леер этот по факту?

Comment: Этот леер не должен быть там всегда. Держать в шаблоне целые блоки html-css-js которые не всегда используются - вот это порно. Леер должен появляться при определённом url. По факту он вызывается через ajax+history если кликнуть на кнопку, или сразу должен быть - если зашли по url напрямую.

Comment: ну дак не должен пусть и не будет, скриптом его вставляешь обычным как только он появится. Вот это как раз нормально

Comment: Если только ajax, т.к. как я упоминал выше - леер должен принимать объект со множеством параметров, сформированный связкой контроллер-модель. Но это получается двойной запрос на сервер - один для формирования страницы, второй для леера. Зачем тогда у View есть метод render? Каково его практическое применение?

Comment: практическое применение render не встречал, а вот на счет переменных, что мешает выдать их заранее во вьюшку, и скриптом вызвать леер с этими переменными?

Comment: леер это 90 строк кода, как html, так и js, + подключение css и jquery плагинов. Как вы предлагаете вставить всё это красиво скриптом без аякса?) При этом предполагается повторное использование кода. Поэтому оно у меня и хранится в отдельной вьюхе как универсальное решение, которое можно вызвать откуда угодно.

Comment: легко и просто предлагаю) и я не могу понять в чем проблема ну никак))))

Comment: Будьте добры, пример кода скрипта, который вы предлагаете?

Comment: а что активирует этот леер?

Comment: в данной задаче ничто, просто зайдя по определённому URL он должен показаться.